# Unity | webCamScript not displaying

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the code exact from a tutorial I copied, and the webcam is inserted and works. But when I load the Unity game (In Unity Editor) there is no "No Device connected" error or incorrect scripts. I'm confused as to why it isn't working.

Why isn't it being displayed?

My webCamScript

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class webCamScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject webCameraPlane;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        if (Application.isMobilePlatform) {
            GameObject cameraParent = new GameObject ("camParent");
            cameraParent.transform.position = this.transform.position;
            this.transform.parent = cameraParent.transform;
            cameraParent.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, 90);
        }

        Input.gyro.enabled = true;

        WebCamTexture webCameraTexture = new WebCamTexture ();
        webCameraPlane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTexture = webCameraTexture;
        webCameraTexture.Play ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Quaternion cameraRotation = new Quaternion (Input.gyro.attitude.x, Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.x, -Input.gyro.attitude.y);
        this.transform.localRotation = cameraRotation;
    }
}
```

---

#### Solved

I found the problem, I had a custom texture on the plane which was stopping the camera texture from being inserted.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I presume it has something to do with the fact that you have your code wrapped in an if statement that is checking to see if you are running on a mobile platform. The editor will not be classed as a mobile platform and hence that code will be ignored